# ¿Por qué al evaluar un valor que no es boolean en JavaScript dentro de un if, éste me devuelve un true o false?

Tags: javascript

Verán, estaba practicando condicionales y usando el operador de corto circuito para asignar un valor a una variable,no comprendí muy bien porque los valores se consideran verdaderos o falsos aunque estos no sean booleanos.

Probe este ejemplo

```js
let hola,hola2="Hola mundo"
hola = hola2 || "Adios"
```

En este caso el valor que obtuve fue el valor de hola2 al ser considerado verdadero.

Mientras que en este otro ejemplo usando &&

```js
let hola,hola2="Hola mundo"
hola = hola2 && "Adios"
```

Obtuve el segundo valor que en este caso es "Adios"

Segun lo que aprendi de los operadores de corto circuito al usarlos para asignar un valor a una variable, es que en el caso de usar el operador || si el primer valor es verdadero asignara el primer valor a la variable y si es falso asignara el segundo valor. En el caso del operador && si el primer valor es verdadero se asigna el segundo valor a la variable y si no se le asigna el primero.

Hice otra prueba realizando este ejemplo con if:

```js
let persona="Hola mundo";

if(persona){
 console.log("Hola mundo");
}

persona=null;

if(persona){
 console.log("No es null o undefined");
}else{
 console.log("Es null o undefined");
}
```

Mi duda es ¿Porque, a mis variables se les considera con valor verdadero o falso si no son booleanas? valor verdadero cuando tienen un valor almacenado y falso cuando son undefined o null. ¿Es propio del lenguaje hacer eso?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En Javascript hay un concepto que llamamos [*Truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

> En JavaScript, un valor verdadero es un valor que se considera 
>   true/verdadero cuando es evaluado en un contexto Booleano. Todos los
>   valores son verdaderos a menos que se definan como falso (es decir,
>   excepto false, 0, "", null, undefined, y NaN).

Usando la [*coerción de tipos*](http://www.etnassoft.com/2011/04/06/coercion-de-datos-en-javascript/) de Javascript (obligar al intérprete a cambiar los tipos de las variables para operar con ellas) , puedes comprobarlo con pruebas sencillas:

```js
console.log('Booleano', true);

//Usamos la doble negación para forzar la transformación a boolean
console.log('Cadena vacía', !!''); 
console.log('cero', !!0);
console.log('números distintos de cero', !!-1, !!3);
console.log('Cadena no vacía',!!'hola');
console.log('Null', !!null);
console.log('Array vacío y con elementos',!![],!![1]);
console.log('Cualquier objeto',!!{});
```

Esta característica es útil para hacer comprobaciones rápidas sobre si un campo se ha rellenado:

```
if (input.value) {
  // Entramos si el input no es una cadena vacía
}
```

o para comprobar que un atributo existe:

```
if (obj.prop1) {
  // si prop1 es null o undefined no entramos
}
```

Pero hay que tener cuidado si el valor es un número, porque si `prop1` es 0 puede ser un valor correcto, en ese caso tendrías que hacer algo como

```
if (typeof obj.prop !== 'number')
```

Otra utilidad es para tomar valores por defecto: imagina que tienes que comprobar si un atributo existe y, si no existe, asignarle un valor:

```js
function concatena (str1, str2) {
  return str1 + str2;
}

console.log(concatena('ho','la'));
console.log('Segundo parámetro omitido', concatena('ho'));

function concatena2 (str1, str2) {
  
  str2 = str2 || ''; //si el segundo parámetro de la funciónn es "Falsy", asumimos una cadena vacía
  return str1 + str2;
}

console.log('Segundo parámetro omitido', concatena2('ho'));
```

Se pueden crear condicionales, aunque sea bastante feo:

```
a && f(a);
```

Esto hace que se ejecute `f(a)` sólo si `a` existe y tiene un valor *truthy*, porque la operación `&&` se *cortocircuita* (no se ejecuta la segunda parte si la primera no se cumple)

Comment: Muchas gracias por aclarar mi duda, aunque tenia aun otra inquietud aun Pablo,¿Cuando se usa el operador de corto circuito como el || y el && para asignar el valor dependiendo de el valor de un operando?, tiene algo que ver la conjunción y disyunción en la resolución del valor, o la manera de funcionar de este tipo de operación no tiene nada que ver con eso?, creo que no, pero quiero estar seguro de ello. ¿Aparte de para asignar un valor a una variable, podría usarlo en alguna otra parte del código en la que me pueda servir este tipo de operación?

Comment: Estuve probando en la consola metiendo por ejemplo "Hola" || ' ' y me dio el mismo resultado que cuando lo use para asignar el valor a  una variable, osea que vendria siendo como cualquier otra expresion de toda la vida como una suma por ejemplo? lo puedo ver de ese modo?

Comment: El funcionamiento es exactamente igual que en una condición: a || b podría leer "Nos quedamos con a si es *truthy*, en otro caso nos quedamos con b". Y, tras quedarnos con uno u otro, si hace falta se hará una coerción de tipos.