# ¿Por qué mi if not no funciona y por que mi while es infinito?

Tags: javascript

```
let again
let puntos= 0
let intentos=0
/*
alert('Bienvenido a Preguntados! Este juego consistirá en que tendrás que responder dos preguntas correctas de cada una de las 5 categorías que tiene este juego para ganar.')
alert('Las preguntas tienen puntos, y mientras más puntos tengan, más difícil será la pregunta.')
alert('Cada categoría es más difícil que la anterior, y para poder pasar de categoría en categoría, tendrás que responder dos preguntas correctamente de esa categoría.')
alert('Ganas si conestatas 10 preguntas correctas en total, en cada categoría tendrás tres oportunidades de fallar, si fallas una cuarta vez, habrás perdido.')  */

 let preguntasEntretenimiento = {
 '100' : {
    pregunta : '¿Cómo se llama la cuarta película de Harry Potter? El cáliz de fuego, el misterio del príncipe, la piedra filosofal o la orden del Fénix (Responde 1, 2, 3 o 4)',
    respuesta : 1
  },
  '200' : {
    pregunta: '¿Cómo se llama el personaje de la mejor amiga de Mia Thermopolis en la película "El Diario de la Princesa"? Lilly, Emma, Anna, Bonny (Responde 1,2,3 o 4)',
    respuesta : 1
  },
    '300' : {
    pregunta : '¿Quién es la artista más joven en ganar un premio Country?  Dolly Parton, Miley Cyrus, Taylor Swift, Carrie Underwood (Responde 1, 2, 3, 4)',
    respuesta : 3
  },
    '400' : {
    pregunta : ' ¿Quién es el creador del talent show "The X Factor"? Louis Walsh, Simon Cowell, Sharon Osbourne, Nicole Scherzinger ',
    respuesta : 3
  },
    '500' : {
    pregunta : '¿En qué año se estrenó la película de Disney "Pinocho"? 1940, 1944, 1930, 1960',
    respuesta : 1
    }
    }
  let preguntas = {
 '100' : {
    pregunta: '¿Qué color consigues mezclando todos los colores del CMYK? Negro, blanco, cafe, gris (Responde 1,2,3 o 4)',
    respuesta : 1
  },
  '200' : {
    pregunta: '¿Cuál compositor de música clásica era zurdo? Beethoven, Mozart, Vivaldi, Chaikovski',
    respuesta : 1
  },
    '300' : {
    pregunta : ' ¿Dónde se encontraba el cuadro "El Grito"?  Italia, Francia, España, Mexico',
    respuesta : 2
  },
    '400' : {
    pregunta : ' ¿Cuál de las siguientes no pertenece a las 7 maravillas del mundo antiguo? Los Jardines Colgantes de Babilonia, el Templo de Artemisa en Éfeso, la Estatua de Zeus en Olimpia, El Coliseo Romano',
    respuesta : 3
  },
    '500' : {
    pregunta : '¿A partir de cuántas sílabas se considera verso de arte mayor? 7, 8, 9, 10',
    respuesta : 3
  }
  }
   let preguntasCiencia = {
 '100' : {
    pregunta: '¿Dónde tienen el sentido del gusto las moscas? En las patas, En la lengua, En la nariz, En los ojos',
    respuesta : 1
  },
  '200' : {
    pregunta: '¿De qué país proviene del pez dorado? Australia, China, Japón, Brazil',
    respuesta : 2
  },
    '300' : {
    pregunta : '¿Cómo se llama la arteria principal del cuerpo humano? Arteria coronaria izquierda,  Arteria coronaria derecha, Arteria circunfleja, Aorta', 
    respuesta : 4
  },
    '400' : {
    pregunta : '¿Qué parte del cuerpo tiene 27 huesos y 35 músculos? Pie, Cara, Mano, Rodilla',
    respuesta : 3
  },
    '500' : {
    pregunta : ' ¿Cuántas células de esperma fabrican los testículos de un hombre al día? 10 millones, 100 mil, 10 mil, mil', 
    respuesta : 1
  }
  }

  let preguntasGeografia = {
 '100' : {
    pregunta: '¿Cuántas estrellas tiene la bandera de China? 4, 5, 6, 7',
    respuesta : 2
  },
  '200' : {
    pregunta: '¿Cuál es la capital de Nueva Zelanda? Auckland, Queenstown, Wellington, Chirstchruch',
    respuesta : 3
  },
    '300' : {
    pregunta : ' Cómo se le conoce a los habitantes de Málaga? Ramblos, Malaguenses, Malágonos, Boquerones', 
    respuesta : 4
  },
    '400' : {
    pregunta : ' ¿Cómo se les llama a los habitantes de Huelva?  Españoles, Huelvaenses, Huelvanos, Onubenses',
    respuesta : 4
  },
    '500' : {
    pregunta : ' ¿Cuál es el sexto país más grande el mundo?  Estados Unidos, China, Australia, India ', 
    respuesta : 3
  }
  }
  let preguntasHistoria = {
 '100' : {
    pregunta: '¿Cuántos mandamientos hay en el cristianismo? 10, 22, 540, 5',
    respuesta : 1
  },
  '200' : {
    pregunta: '¿Quién gobernó Francia desde 1799 a 1815? Jean Jacques Régis de Cambacérès,  Napoleón Bonaparte, Jerónimo Bonaparte, François Arago ',
    respuesta : 2
  },
    '300' : {
    pregunta : ' ¿Con qué hombre estuvo casada Cleopatra? Marco Antonio, Ptolomeo XIII, Ptolomeo XIV, Todas son correctas', 
    respuesta : 4
  },
    '400' : {
    pregunta : ' ¿Qué país fue dirigido por Stalin? Unión Soviética, Rusia, Ucrania, República Checa',
    respuesta : 1
  },
    '500' : {
    pregunta :  ' ¿En qué país nació el protestantismo?  China, India, Reino Unido, Alemania  ', 
    respuesta : 3
  }
  }
  let name = prompt('Antes de iniciar, ¿Cómo te llamas?')
 // do {   //
  do {
   alert(name+', la primera categoría es Entretenimiento')
        let valor = prompt('Elige el valor de tu pregunta (puedes elegir entre 100, 200, 300, 400 y 500)')
        let seleccion = preguntasEntretenimiento  [valor];
        if (seleccion !== '100' || '200' || '300' || '400' || '500') {
            alert('Opción no válida');
        } else {
          let respuesta = + prompt(seleccion.preguntaEntretenimiento); //el + transforma a números
          if (respuesta === seleccion.respuesta) {
            puntos += (+valor);
            alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la pregunta. Tienes ' +puntos+' puntos.');
          } else {
            alert('¡Lo siento '+name+', has respondido incorrectamente la pregunta. Tienes ' +puntos+' puntos.');
          }
          intentos++;
        }

    } while ( intentos < 3)
/*
again = confirm('¿Quiéres volver a jugar?')
} while (again)    */
```

Bueno, estoy trabajando en un juego parecido a preguntados en el cual tengo distintas categorias de preguntas, y se supone que no se debe pasar a la segunda categoría hasta tener mínimo dos aciertos ( de preguntas correctas) y tiene máximo tres oportunidades por categoria. Por el momento llevo hechos los arrays para las preguntas de cada categoria e hice el do de ls categoría de entretenimiento pero estoy teniendo algunos problemas. Primero, puse en una parte del código " if (seleccion !== '100' || '200' || '300' || '400' || '500')". Mi intencion con esto es que si el usuario no elige una de esas opciones me lo marque como error, pero incluso cuando eligo esas opciones lo marca como error. 
Mi otro problema es que estoy en un loop infinito. Hice un do para la cateogoria entretenimiento en el que se van sumando los intentos que llevo para que cuando sean 3 intentos me saque automaticamente pero no funcionan así.

Comment: Me parece que tus comparaciones están escritas de manera errónea, deberían ser así: `(seleccion !== '100' || seleccion !== '200' `, es decir por cada `OR` debes invocar a la variable en cuestión

Comment: Complementando el comentario dr Aprendiz to while es infinito porque solo incrementas la variable intentos en el bloque else que nunca se da por lo explicado por Aprendiz

Comment: @Fernanda cuando hayas arreglado el programa, por favor deja la solución para que podamos echar una partidilla al preguntados ^_^

Answer (score 4):

Tienes dos cosas mal: lo que comparas y cómo lo comparas

```
let valor = prompt('Elige el valor de tu pregunta (puedes elegir entre 100, 200, 300, 400 y 500)')
let seleccion = preguntasEntretenimiento  [valor];
if (seleccion !== '100' || '200' || '300' || '400' || '500') {
  alert('Opción no válida');
} else {
  ...
}
```

Lo que ocurre aquí:

1. Digamos que el usuario escribe '100' y eso se guarda en `valor`.
2. En `seleccion`, por tanto, guardamos el valor de `preguntasEntretenimiento['100']`. Eso significa que `seleccion` vale

```
seleccion = {
  pregunta : '¿Cómo se llama la cuarta película de Harry Potter? El cáliz de fuego, el misterio del príncipe, la piedra filosofal o la orden del Fénix (Responde 1, 2, 3 o 4)',
  respuesta : 1
}
```

3. Ahora haces la siguiente comprobación:

```
if (seleccion !== '100' || '200' || '300' || '400' || '500') { ... }
```

Pero mira lo que pasa realmente cuando haces esto:

```js
let seleccion = {} //lo que sea
let resultado = (seleccion !== '100' || '200' || '300' || '400' || '500');

console.log(resultado);
```

¿Qué ocurre aquí? Esto se llama [*coerción de tipos*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/263663/porque-al-evaluar-un-valor-que-no-es-boolean-en-javascript-dentro-de-un-if-este/263683#263683), y significa que Javascript transforma cada componente de la condición en un booleano:

```
(seleccion !== 100)  || // false
'200' || //se transforma en true
'300' || //se transforma en true
...
```

Porque cualquier valor que no sea `0`, un string vacío (`''`) , `false`, `null`, `undefined` o NaN es considerado `true`.

Además, `seleccion` hemos dicho que es un objeto... si se ha encontrado dentro de `preguntasEntretenimiento`. Por tanto podrías sustituir toda la condición por:

```
if (seleccion) { ... }
```

A causa de este problema, la variable intentos no se incrementa nunca y causa que el bucle sea infinito, al arreglar el error debería funcionar correctamente.

Answer (score -1):

Tambien puedes usar

```
    var opcionesPosibles = ["100", "200", "300", "400", "500"];
    if (n = opcionesPosibles.includes(seleccion)) {
```

en vez de

```
        if (seleccion !== '100' || '200' || '300' || '400' || '500') {
```

Comment: Hola E-Rick, esta es una solución interesante. Por favor, considera añadir una breve descripción con lo que hace `includes` y una explicación de por qué soluciona esto y fallaba el código de la pregunta. Saludos.